# How to change view on click of button in angular2

Tags: angular

I have just started learning angular 2. What i want to achieve is when i click on item view will change and display item details.

[image]

When i click on 60074190 view should get change and display item details like this

[image]

I don't have any idea how to achieve this i have two component 1.item and 2. item details both are inside transfer folder. i'm using transfer routing to route to item page but now on click of item name i want to change my view and display item details. Please guide me how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) create an object of STO , sto.model.ts

```
    export class Sto {
      id: number;
      trackingNumber: string;
      transferType: string; //or create an enum
    }
```

2) create a mock of the STOs to store few Stos, which later will be called by a service, sto.mock.ts

```
    import { Sto} from "./sto.model.ts";
    export const STOS: Sto[] = {
    {id: 600071498}, trackingNumber: 'AB123', transferType: 'S2S'},
    {id: 600071577}, trackingNumber: 'CD123', transferType: 'S2S'}
    }
```

3) create a service to call for the component to get all product, and also product by Id , Sto.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import { Sto } from "./sto.model.ts";
    import { STOS } from "./sto.mock.ts";

    @Injectable()
    export class StoService {
       getStos(): Product[] {
         return STOS;
       }

       getSto(stoId: number): Product {
        let result: Product;
        result = STOS.find(x => x.id === stoId);

        if (result) {
           return result;
        } else {
          return new Sto();
        }
      }
    }
```

4) in your ItemComponent import 'Router' from @angular/router, import sto model 
   and services inject the sto 
   service, create a Sto property, populate the data in the ngOnInit, and bind 
   it in your html

```
    import { Router } from "@angular/router";
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { StoService } from "./stoService.service.ts";
    import { Sto } from "./sto.model.ts";

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-item',
    templateUrl: './item.component.html'

    export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
      stos: Sto[];
      sto: Product;

   constructor(private stoService: StoService, private route: 
   Router) {
      this.stos= []; //initialize the stos collection

      this.sto= new Product(); //initialze the sto
   }

   ngOnInit() {
        this.stos = this.stoService.getStos();

   }

   navigateToItemDetails(stoId) {
    this.route.navigate(['item-details', stoId]);
  }
```

})

in your sto.component.html you will have to make the STO # to be a link with clickable event, probably have something like this

```
    <a href="javascript:;" (click)="navigateToItemDetails(sto.id)"> {{sto.Id}}></a>
```

5)in your ItemDetailsComponent, import all the below dependencies

```
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
    import { Product } from "../models/product.model";
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { ProductService } from "../services/product.service";

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-item-details',
       templateUrl: './item-details.component.html'})

   export class ItemDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges 
   {
     sto: Sto;
     stoId: string;
     private subscription: Subscription;

     constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private route: 
      Router, private stoService: StoService) { }

     ngOnInit() { //subscribe to read the params sent from ItemComponent
      this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
        this.productId = params['id'];
        this.sto = this.stoService.getSto(this.stoId);
    });

    ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

6) as you can see, from the id, u traverse through the data in the sto mock via the service, and get the sto object, which later you can manipulate accordingly in your html

```
 <p> Tracking #: {{sto.trackingNumber}}</p>
```

7) dont forget to register your service, and components in the app.module.ts

```
   //other imports
   import { StoService } from "./sto.service";
   import { ItemComponent } from './item.component';
   import { ItemDetailsComponent } from './item-details.component';
   import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


   @NgModule({
     imports: [//othhermoduleimports, RouterModule],
     declarations: [//othercomponent, ItemComponent, ItemDetailsComponent]
     providers: [ StoService],
```

and remember to add the routing for this, you can google that.its quite easy

8) And add to your routes

```
    { path: 'item-details/:id', component: ItemDetailsComponent}
    // the :id will be the parameter sent to the ItemDetailsComponent
```

Happy coding and welcome to angular :)